# Template deduction with Eigen arguments

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

```
template <typename Derived>
void Fun(const std::vector<Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>> &seqs);

void Test() {
  std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> _seqs;
  Fun(_seqs);
}
```

As tutored by [functions taking eigen types](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html), `Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>` should accept `Eigen::MatrixXd`. However, the above code could not compiled with error message says `mismatched types ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>’ and ‘Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>’` and the template arguments deduction failed.

So why this happens and how should we deal with it?

Thanks

Comment: You are not right there. Nobody said there that *Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> should accept Eigen::MatrixXd*. There is said the following: *Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& should accept Eigen::MatrixXd&*. Moreover template deduction works with exact matches, not with template parameters implcit casts.

Comment: Even without Eigen, you can't just pass a `vector` of derived objects as a `vector` of base objects: https://wandbox.org/permlink/8kI94kaboGxVWiWD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because [the rule](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#4.3) that `template-name<T>` **as a whole parameter** (ignoring reference and cv-qualifiers) can be deduced from `D` if `D` is derived from `template-name<T>` for some `T`. This rule does not apply for `std::vector<template-name<T>>`.

Even if you explicitly specify the type, since there is no valid conversion from `std::vector<Derived>` to `std::vector<Base>`, the call is still ill-formed.

Besides S.M.'s solution, you can use meta programming.

```
template <
    typename T,
    // enable only if T is derived from Eigen::MatrixBase<T>
    typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Eigen::MatrixBase<T>, T>::value, int> = 0
>
void Fun(const std::vector<T>&);
```

Comment: This is a completely valid solution, but maybe a bit overcomplicated (depends on what the OP actually wants to do).

Answer (score 1):

You should declare function and variable like below

```
template <typename Derived>
void Fun(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>>> &seqs);

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>>> _seqs;
```

And fill the vector with pointers to `Eigen::MatrixXd`:

```
_seq.emplace_back(new Eigen::MatrixXd);
```

**UPDATE** @chtz informed me that `Eigen::MatrixBase` (inherits `struct EigenBase`) has no virtual destructor. Thus my solution above is not proper. The only ways left

1. Use `std::transform()` to get `std::vector<Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>*>` from `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>>>`.
2. Solution offered by @xskxzr

Comment: This will leak memory, since the destructor of `Eigen::MatrixBase` is not virtual. [Simplified demonstration](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XC2BKdBlBLAFyLaB)

Comment: Thank you @chtz In this case it is a strange requirement of OP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a point in accepting a `vector` of `Eigen::MatrixBase` objects.
I don't know your use case, but it usually only makes sense to store the actual `Matrix` objects inside the `vector`. And passing that to a templated function is easy:

```
template<class S, int rows, int cols> 
void func(std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<S, rows, cols> > const &) { }
```

[Usage example](https://godbolt.org/g/bNxu5K)

Note: You can add more template parameters, for template parameters which have defaults, e.g., MatrixOptions or the allocator of the `vector`. The same way, you can leave out template parameters, e.g., if `S` is always `double`.